# IPython's autoreload works with ipyparallel?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using ipyparallel's parallel computation on IPython.
In my environment, all codes are shared since I work at a directory on NFS
which is working on every machine I use as an engine.
Is it able to automatically reload modules on engines?

I tried `autoreload`, but it does not work as I expected.
It does not reload the dependent modules correctly.
What I tried is:

- import with `sync_imports`
- activate autoreload locally (on the client)
- activate autoreload on engines as follows:

  ```
  def magic(command):
      from IPython import get_ipython
      return get_ipython().magic(command)
  c.apply_sync(magic, "autoreload 2")
  ```